# How to join related tree repository with TypeORM

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I have this situation:

This is my tree entity where each item can be a parent item or child item of one of the same entity and each of them are related to an artist.

```
@Entity()
@Tree("materialized-path")
export class ArtistCommissionSetupItem {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({type: "bigint"})
    id:number
 
    @ManyToOne(()=>Artist, artist => artist.id, {onDelete: 'CASCADE'})
    @JoinColumn()
    @Index()
    artist:Artist

    @Column()
    @Index()
    name:string
 
    @Index()
    @Column({nullable: true})
    enabled:boolean

    @TreeParent()
    parent:ArtistCommissionSetupItem

    @TreeChildren()
    childrens:ArtistCommissionSetupItem[]

}
```

The thing here is that I want to get the artist with his related commission setup items and I can do that but the result of commission setup items leftJoinAndSelect method doesn't come with the items nested as tree/child tree. I want the data of commission setup items come like `findTrees()` method returns it.

An example of how the data come:

```
"commissionSetupItems": [
        {
            "id": "154",
            "name": "Body",
            "enabled": null,
            "price": null,
            "createdAt": "2021-09-23T21:17:05.630Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-09-23T21:17:05.630Z"
        },
        {
            "id": "155",
            "name": "icon",
            "enabled": true,
            "price": "120.00",
            "createdAt": "2021-09-23T21:17:05.630Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-09-23T21:17:05.630Z"
        },
        {
            "id": "156",
            "name": "Headshot",
            "enabled": false,
            "price": "120.00",
            "createdAt": "2021-09-23T21:17:05.630Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-09-23T21:17:05.630Z"
        }
}
```

an example of how I want the data comes:

```
{
    "commissionSetupItems": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Characters",
            "key": "characters",
            "childrens": [
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "name": "Number of characters",
                    "key": "number_of_characters",
                    "childrens": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Body",
            "key": "body",
            "childrens": [
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "name": "Icon",
                    "key": "icon",
                    "childrens": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 7,
                    "name": "Chibi",
                    "key": "chibi",
                    "childrens": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 8,
                    "name": "Headshot",
                    "key": "headshot",
                    "childrens": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 9,
                    "name": "Torso or Burst",
                    "key": "torso",
                    "childrens": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 10,
                    "name": "Half body",
                    "key": "half_body",
                    "childrens": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 11,
                    "name": "Full body",
                    "key": "full_body",
                    "childrens": []
                }
            ]
        }
}
```

I can't figure out how to do this.